# Best JPA ID Generation Strategy for Batch Insertion

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue while inserting 100 000 records at once using spring data JPA repository. When we execute `repo.save(List<Objs>)` it is taking a lot of time if we use Sequence generator as it queries the database for the nextval. I am using Oracle, which ID generation is best here?

Comment: What is your sequence generator configuration?

Comment: Java Config        @SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ_GEN")          DB Sequence:   CREATE SEQUENCE  MY_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;

Answer (score 5):

Sequence generator is probably a good choice, but you have to tweak its parameters.

In your particular case, I'd start experimenting with allocation size, and then with strategy. 
See for example: [JPA/Hibernate bulk inserts slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780362/jpa-hibernate-bulk-inserts-slow)

Take a look at the optimizers configuration:
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/

Note that your configuration resolves to:

- `SequenceHiLoGenerator` on Hibernate 4
- `SequenceStyleGenerator` on Hibernate 5, (it has `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` set to true)

You cannot use identity generator (see [Hibernate disabled insert batching when using an identity identifier generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/hibernate-disabled-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-generator))

Table generator is not the best performant one (https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Additionally, make sure that the number of `nextval()` is the actual problem.
Maybe changing batch size or statement ordering will help (see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/)

Comment: What about using a GUID generator?  I would think that's the best without needing to grab a sequence at all and not having to wait for insert?

Answer (score 1):

`allocationSize=1` is  the real issue here. With this configuration hibernate will call `nextVal()` for each insert so if you have 1000 inserts then hibernate  will call `nextVal()` a 1000 times.

For more information refer to this article by [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/)